# C# How do I make a switch ignore invalid input?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple console game that starts with a title screen. The user inputs 'N' for a new game, 'L' to load a game, or 'E' to exit. I have this set up as a switch, but I need to know how to make the program ignore any input other than the aforementioned keys. I've Googled this question but didn't find an answer. Please help if you can.

I don't see much point in posting the code as 10 lines of a simple switch probably wouldn't be terribly helpful to solving the problem. Also, if there would be an easier / more efficient way than a switch, I would love to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your switch case code ?

Comment: There is *always* a point to posting the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`default:` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to handle the other (unknown) cases:

```
switch(inputString.ToLower())
{
     case "n":
       // Handle new
       break;
     //.. handle known cases
     default:
         Console.WriteLine("Unknown option chosen.  Please enter valid option:");
         // Re-read values, etc?
         break;
}
```

Anything not specified in one of your other cases will fall into the `default` case, which you can then use to prompt for valid input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually ignore all keys other than valid ones you could do something like this:

```
public static char ReadKey(IEnumerable<char> validKeys)
{
    var validKeySet = new HashSet<char>(validKeys);
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (validKeySet.Contains(key.KeyChar))
        {
            //you could print it out if you wanted.
            //Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            return key.KeyChar;
        }
        else
        {
            //you could print an error message here if you wanted.
        }
    }
}
```

When you use `ReadKey(true)` the `true` indicated that it will intercept that key and not display it on the console.  This gives you the option of determining if it's valid or invalid.

Comment: Also that `HashSet` step is a important one, it greatly speeds up the look-up process. You many not notice any difference with this specific use case, but if you are trying to filter out some invalid characters coming out of a `StreamReader` before it gets passed on to something like a XML reader it can make a huge difference.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, it kinda depends.  If you never actually fail then it will actually be slower, as the work of populating the hashset it more than a single search.  It also depends on the size of the key set (if it's tiny then it won't ever matter).  However, the main reason I did it was to ensure that the input sequence is never iterated more than once.  If the parameter is actually the result of a query or other complex deferred operation then iterating it twice could be very bad.

Comment: Note that re-structuring this so that it is able to re-use a single hashset (or just pass the hash set into the function directly) would be best from an efficiency point of view.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I meant to imply using a single hash set like you recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If a `switch` statement does not have a `default` block, and if the expression being switched on does not match any of the `case` blocks, the `switch` statement does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only 3 cases, a switch isn't much more efficient than just a simple `if-else` construct.

```
if (input == "N")
{
    // New game
}
else if (input == "L")
{
    // Load game
}
else if (input == "E")
{
    // Exit game
}
// if none of the cases match, the input is effectively ignored.
```

If you insist on using a switch, then your construct is very similar:

```
switch (input)
{
    case "N":
        //New Game
        break;
    case "L":
        //Load Game
        break;
    case "E":
        //Exit Game
        break;
    default:
        //Do nothing (ignore unmatched inputs)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, guys. I managed to solve the problem by doing the following:

```
static void titleInput()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo titleOption = Console.ReadKey(true);

        switch (titleOption.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.N:
                Console.Clear();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.L:
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.E:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                titleInput();
                break;

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how 'proper' this is, but it does what I need it to do. Any keys other than 'N', 'L', and 'E' no longer do anything.